# Want to fetch feature details based on Feature title for workitem type feature in Azure DevOps using C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I am trying to develop a console application to fetch the workitem details for workitem type Feature in Azure DevOps.

I want to fetch details like Feature id,state. the title of Feature will contain Demand number along with demand name, I will be knowing the Demand number which is in Feature Title and want fetch the feature id if exists.

I am using these Nuget package for my code:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to connect to the service wit [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts) and get the work item client:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, PAT));
WitClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
```

If you know a work item id, you can get a work item and find all its fields in the Fields dictionary:

```
var wi = WitClient.GetWorkItemAsync(Id).Result;
foreach (var fieldName in wi.Fields.Keys)
Console.WriteLine(“{0,-40}: {1}”, fieldName, wi.Fields[fieldName].ToString());
```

If you try to find a work item through the title contents, you can use the wiql query:

```
string queryWiqlList = @"SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'TEAM_PROJECT_NAME' and [System.Title] Contains '<YOUR SEARCH_TEXT>' and [System.State] <> 'Removed' and [System.State] <> 'Closed'";

Wiql wiql = new Wiql();
wiql.Query = wiqlStr;
WorkItemQueryResult result = WitClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

if (result != null)
{
    if (result.WorkItems != null) // this is Flat List 
        foreach (var wiRef in result.WorkItems)
        {
            var wi = WitClient.GetWorkItemAsync(wiRef.Id).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", wi.Id, wi.Fields["System.Title"].ToString()));
        }
}
```

Comment: @BSS Accepts my answer. Maybe someone also will find it useful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers